# include css and images when rewriting url to remote server

Tags: css, image, apache

I have an apache http server and I want to redirect certain URL to an external(remote) site, so I set the following line in the httpd.conf file :

```
RewriteRule ^/datafeeds/customer_feed.jsp http://othersite.com/datafeeds/customer_feed.jsp [P]
```

the problem is that the page is returning without the css and images (all resources) because it's put as relative paths in the remote site .... I need all the css and images to appear normally as if I am opening the remote site from the browser, how can I do it?

Comment: So the othersite showing the data is showing without resources? What does the URL look like in Chrome DEV tools that is coming back 404?

Comment: yes , the resources urls are giving 404 ......because it's looking for the resources on the local machine not the remote

Answer (score 0):

I simply modified the rule to include all resources :

```
RewriteRule ^/datafeeds/(.+)$ http://othersite.com/datafeeds/$1 [P]
```